# Evitar múltiples toggle con misma clase

Tags: javascript

Para un evento toggle con puro javascript lo desarrollo de la siguiente forma:

**Javascript**

```
 // Esta clase lo expande.
const expandButton = document.querySelector('.expand-button');
expandButton.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
    //Esta es la clase que muestra el contenido.
    const more = document.querySelector('.more');
   //El contenido pasa de oculto a ser visible.
   more.style.display = 'block';
  //Oculto la imagen al expandir.
   if (more.style.display === 'block') {
       expandButton.style.display = 'none';
   }
}, false);
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="more"> Contenido 1 </div> <!-- El contenido -->
<div class="expand-button">Expandir</div> <!-- Botón que expande -->
```

El problema está en que si tengo otro toogle con la misma clase

```
<div class="more"> Contenido 2 </div> <!-- El contenido -->
<div class="expand-button">Expandir</div> <!-- Botón que expande -->
```

Debería de recuperar los elementos con la clase expand-button con un **for()**, cuando lo hago, el botón expandir del segundo toggle abre al primero, y el primero realiza su función correctamente.

¿Alguna solución?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema ocurre por esta línea de código:

```
const more = document.querySelector('.more');
```

Como haces la selección con `querySelector` y hay varios elementos con la clase "more", entonces el navegador se queda sólo con el primero, pulses en el botón de expandir que pulses.

Una posible solución sería, si puedes, añadir un `data-atributo` al botón de expandir que le indique cuál de los `.more` debe abrirse (y añadirle un id a cada uno de los contenedores). Algo como esto:

```
<div id="contenido1" class="more"> Contenido 1 </div>
<div class="expand-button" data-toggle="#contenido1">Expandir</div>

<div id="contenido2" class="more"> Contenido 2 </div>
<div class="expand-button" data-toggle="#contenido2">Expandir</div>
```

Entonces el JavaScript cambiaría para seleccionar no el ".more" sino el id especificado en el `data-toggle`. Aquí dejo un ejemplo funcionando:

```js
const expandButton = document.querySelectorAll('.expand-button');

expandButton.forEach(function(el, arr) {
    el.addEventListener('click', (e)=> {
        //Esta es la clase que muestra el contenido.
        var more = document.querySelector(e.target.dataset.toggle);
        //El contenido pasa de oculto a ser visible.
        more.style.display = 'block';
        //Oculto la imagen al expandir.
        if (more.style.display === 'block') {
            el.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }, false);
});
```

```css
.more { display:none }
```

```html
<div id="contenido1" class="more"> Contenido 1 </div>
<div class="expand-button" data-toggle="#contenido1">Expandir</div>

<div id="contenido2" class="more"> Contenido 2 </div>
<div class="expand-button" data-toggle="#contenido2">Expandir</div>
```

---

Actualización: como se menciona en los comentarios, el código presenta problemas en algunas versions de Internet Explorer. Eso ocurre porque se usan un par de cosas (`forEach` y la notación `=>` para funciones) que no están bien soportadas en versiones "antiguas" de IE.

Estos problemas se pueden solucionar de manera simple:

- Cambiando el `forEach` por un bucle `for` simple (y las referencias a `el` por referencias al elemento dentro del array que se atraviesa)
- Cambiando `(e) => { ... }` por el tradicional `function(e) { ... }`

Con esos dos cambios, el código ya funciona en Chrome, Firefox e Internet Explorer:

```js
const expandButton = document.querySelectorAll('.expand-button');

for (var x = 0; x < expandButton.length; x++) {
    expandButton[x].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        //Esta es la clase que muestra el contenido.
        var more = document.querySelector(e.target.dataset.toggle);
        //El contenido pasa de oculto a ser visible.
        more.style.display = 'block';
        //Oculto la imagen al expandir.
        if (more.style.display === 'block') {
            e.target.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }, false);
}
```

```css
.more { display:none }
```

```html
<div id="contenido1" class="more"> Contenido 1 </div>
<div class="expand-button" data-toggle="#contenido1">Expandir</div>

<div id="contenido2" class="more"> Contenido 2 </div>
<div class="expand-button" data-toggle="#contenido2">Expandir</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, es lo que buscaba, para un toggle lo tenia claro, el problema venia con mas de 1. Buena solución. Saludos!

Comment: Borre el otro comentario por que ya se que pasa, IE8 y IE 11 la gente se queja del forEach(), parece que no funciona. Buscare una solución compatible con IE. Si compruebas tu solución en IE veras que te da un error en el forEach(), y es que Microsoft nos obliga a trabajar con frameworks por culpa de estas tonterías, llevo 12 horas de reloj para que el toggle sea compatible en todos los navegadores, eso no es productivo.

Comment: @UnderZero_- Ese problema se soluciona cambiando `forEach` por un bucle `for` clásico. Además, tendrás que cambiar la parte de `(e) =>` porque falla en IE también. He actualizado la respuesta para mostrar una versión que funcione en Chrome, Firefox e IE (probado en 11, que es el que tiene esta máquina)

Comment: @AlavaroMontoro Me di cuenta, por eso hice referencia a tu respuesta actualizandolo a un for clásico. Referente a la notación => en 11 si que me funciona, o eso creo, le echare un vistazo pero creo que si. Gracias de nuevo. Buen día

Answer (score 1):

Puedes navegar el DOM desde el botón hacia el hermano anterior, usando la propiedad [`previousSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/previousSibling).

De esta manera obtienes el `<div>` anterior en la estructura y expandes unicamente ese.

Algo así: (fíjate que uso `this.previousSibling` lo cual selecciona únicamente el hermano anterior del botón sobre el que haces click)

```
const expandButton = document.querySelectorAll('.expand-button');
expandButton.addEventListener('click', ()=> {

   const more = this.previousSibling; // aqui se usaria

   //El contenido pasa de oculto a ser visible.
   more.style.display = 'block';
  //Oculto la imagen al expandir.
   if (more.style.display === 'block') {
       expandButton.style.display = 'none';
   }
}, false);
```

Ten en cuenta que esto funciona con la estructura HTML que pones en la pregunta, si cambias la estructura, sera necesario modifacar el codigo para navegar al elemento correcto.

Te recomiendo que leas sobre otras propiedades similares del objeto [Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) tales como `nextSibling`, `parentNode`, etc.

## MAS..

Me acabo de dar cuenta que la forma en que estableces el listener no funcionara para todos los botones con la clase `.expand-button`. Esto se debe a que querySelector toma únicamente el primer elemento que cumpla con la query.

Para asignar el handler a todos los botones deberas usar querySelectorAll y luego iterar sobre el resultado para asignar el manejador a todos los elementos.

Para ES2015:

```
var expandButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.expand-button');

Array.from(expandButtons).forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        
        const more = this.previousSibling; 
        /// resto del código aquí.
       
    });
});
```

Comment: Hola @rnd, la estructura no es la misma, hay varios div y secciones entre ellas, lo puse así para que no sea tan engorroso al publicarlo aquí. Ese es el problema, solo iterando me va correctamente, pero al mostrar el texto de la clase more la primera lo muestra y el segundo abre la primera. Voy a echarle un vistazo a esas propiedades.

Comment: Hola @UnderZero_-, Gracias por aclarar, si puedes intenta resumir la estructura (solo la estructura escencial, sin el contentido) asi se puede dar una respuesta al problema completo.  Saludos

Comment: Estaba preparando la estructura para mostrarla y @AlvaroMontoro publico la solución. Muchas gracias de todas formas, voy a documentarme un poco mas sobre las propiedades del objeto Node. Saludos.

Comment: De nada! la solucion de alvaro es muy buena

Answer (score 0):

La Respuesta que ofreció Alvaro Montoro es correcta, pero tiene un handicap, IE **no soporta** **forEach()**, así que siguiendo la linea que nos muestra Alvaro tuve que cambiar el **forEach** por un **for**, de esta forma el toggle funciona también en IE.

Espero que os sirva de ayuda como me lo ha sido a mi.

```js
const expandButton = document.querySelectorAll('.expand-button');
for (let i = 0; i < expandButton.length; i++) {
    var element = expandButton[i];

    element.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        var more = document.querySelector(e.target.dataset.toggle);
        more.style.display = 'block';   
    }, false);
}
```

```css
.more { display:none }
```

```html
<div id="contenido1" class="more"> Contenido 1 </div>
<div class="expand-button" data-toggle="#contenido1">Expandir</div>

<div id="contenido2" class="more"> Contenido 2 </div>
<div class="expand-button" data-toggle="#contenido2">Expandir</div>
```